# PHP compare user input against multiple variables

Tags: php, loops

I have 5 variables that generate a random number and a sixth variable which is the users input. 
Then I check to see if users input $userNum matches any of the random numbers. I know it's a dumb game, but I'm just messing around to learn more PHP

There has to be an easier way to do this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$userNum = $_POST['userNum'];
$spot1 = rand(1, 100);
$spot2 = rand(1, 100);
$spot3 = rand(1, 100);
$spot4 = rand(1, 100);
$spot5 = rand(1, 100);
echo $spot1 ."<br>" .$spot2 ."<br>" .$spot3 ."<br>" .$spot4 ."<br>" .$spot5;
if($userNum == $spot1)
    {
    echo "you hit a mine!";
    exit();
} 
if($userNum == $spot2)
    {
    echo "you hit a mine!";
    exit();
} 
if($userNum == $spot3)
    {
    echo "you hit a mine!";
    exit();
}
if($userNum == $spot4)
    {
    echo "you hit a mine!";
    exit();
} 
if($userNum == $spot5)
    {
    echo "you hit a mine!";
    exit();
} else {
echo "you lived!";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store spots in an array or anything like that just use a simple loop.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $userNum = (int) $_POST['userNum'];
    $hitMine = false;

    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
        $randNum = rand(1, 100);
        echo $randNum . '<br />';
        if($randNum == $userNum){
            $hitMine = true;    
        }
    }

    if($hitMine == true){
        echo "you hit a mine!"; 
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks this works well, I can up $i <= 50 variables, saves a ton of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would make an array of the spots

```
$spot1 = rand(1, 100);
$spot2 = rand(1, 100);
$spot3 = rand(1, 100);
$spot4 = rand(1, 100);
$spot5 = rand(1, 100);

// Make an array of the spots.
$spots = array($spot1, $spot2, $spot3, $spot4, $spot5);

if(in_array($userNum, $spots)) {
    echo "you hit a mine!";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "you lived!";
}
```

For 50 or more spots you can dynamicaly insert the values in the array assuming you use the rand() function in the real php-code:

```
$spots = Array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i ++) {
    array_push($spots, rand(1,100));
}
```

or:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i ++) {
    $spots[$i] = rand(1,100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted 50+ spots, I'd have to create an array and variable for each?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Switch Case in place of if else to make it better and quick.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$userNum = $_POST['userNum'];
$spot1 = rand(1, 100);
$spot2 = rand(1, 100);
$spot3 = rand(1, 100);
$spot4 = rand(1, 100);
$spot5 = rand(1, 100);
echo $spot1 ."<br>" .$spot2 ."<br>" .$spot3 ."<br>" .$spot4 ."<br>" .$spot5;
Switch($userNum)
{
Case $spot1:
Case $spot2:
Case $spot3:
Case $spot4:
Case $spot5: 
         echo "you hit a mine!";
         break;
default: echo "you lived!";
       break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just store the valid spots in an array.

```
 $myhashmap = array();
 $myhashmap['spot1'] = true;
 $myhashmap['spot2'] = true;

 if(isset($myhashmap[$userNum] ) )
    {
    echo "you hit a mine!";
    exit();
 }
```

Here's a link for more info about PHP arrays: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm